# money-rails gem not allowing me to input cents into textbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, money-rails

I am having problems with saving values to my database using the money-rails gem. Whenever I try and input a value with cents into the textbox (i.e. 20.22) it gives me an error saying **"Please enter a valid value.The two nearest values are 20 and 21."**

Model:

```
class VideoGame < ActiveRecord::Base

    monetize :loose_price_cents, with_model_currency: :price_currency
    monetize :cib_price_cents, with_model_currency: :price_currency
    monetize :new_price_cents, with_model_currency: :price_currency

end
```

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@video_game) do |f| %>
  <% if @video_game.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@video_game.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this video_game from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @video_game.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :game %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :game %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :loose_price %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :loose_price %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :cib_price %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :cib_price %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :new_price %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :new_price %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

controller update function:

```
def update
      respond_to do |format|
      if @video_game.update(video_game_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @video_game, notice: 'Video game was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @video_game }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @video_game.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I have gone into the rails console and changed values around manually, but it seems to base the error off of the database value (db value = 2011 cents, error = "Please enter a valid value.The two nearest values are 20.11 and 21.11.").

Any advice would be appreciated!

Edit:
I figured it out. By adding "step: 0.01" to the end of the number_field method it allows you to increase the value by .01 instead of the 1 by default. It should look like this instead:

```
<%= form_for(@video_game) do |f| %>
  <% if @video_game.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@video_game.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this video_game from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @video_game.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :game %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :game %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :loose_price %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :loose_price, step: 0.01 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :cib_price %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :cib_price, step: 0.01 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :new_price %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :new_price, step: 0.01 %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```